# Variable inside string

Tags: php, string, variables

Lets say I have a string `"My name is $name and my pet is $animal"`

How to check if string has variables inside it? And if has, add to array like

`$array = ("$name","animal");`

Would it be some pregmatch? but then all $+sometextafterthesymbol needs to be extracted and $ with space after it left alone.
Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the input coming from?  If it's hard-coded, you have to change the double-quotes (`"`) to single quotes (`'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this.  The following will match any dollar sign followed by 1 or more word characters (letters, numbers, or underscore):

```
preg_match_all('/\$(\w+)/', $string, $matches);
```

`$matches`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $name
            [1] => $animal
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => animal
        )

)
```

Remember that `$string`, if hardcoded, must be wrapped in single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Although the question does not mention it there are others valid syntaxes that should probably be taken into account, eg: "abc {$somevar} def" or "abc {$obj->property} def".